# Is there a simulator for Salesforce Streaming API?

Tags: streaming-api

- Is there a simulator for Salesforce Streaming API?
- The reason is that minimum session timeout value is 15 mins. So, for some usecases, I would have to wait for minimum 15 minutes to test some code flows.

Answer (score 0):

You can test and monitor the four Streaming APIs with this tool I contributed: [Streaming Monitor](https://github.com/pozil/streaming-monitor)

Comment: is it possible to send error response ( to simulate errors in salesforce streaming ), through Streaming monitor ?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you call "error responses". In any cases, the Streaming Monitor is tied to what the Salesforce APIs allow.